# Promise chain success is executed after first one returns error

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

i have a promise chain, in which the first promise causes a failure, but even then the second promise is getting executed successfully whereas as expected that should have failed...

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQ18Ax6Vg8HhvD79CM2C?p=preview)

what i did was simple:

```
dummyPromise().then(success, error).then(success, error);
```

so if the first one executes error, the subsequent error should be executed but what is get is:

```
 1. error
 2. success
```

why is that so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return `return $q.reject();` from a promise in order for the next promise in the chain to fail too. See forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/porOG8qVg2GkeddzVHu3?p=preview

The reason is straightforward: Your error handler may take action to *correct* the error. Therefore it is not reasonable to have the next promise failing by default. By the way, you can return `$q.reject()` even from a *success* handler, if you sense an error condition, to have the next promise in the chain failing.

Comment: got it, but why the original example does not work? reasoning or logic behind it?

Answer (score 4):

The other answer by Nikos is correct - but I feel like this could benefit from a synchronous analogy:

```
try{
    var val = dummyPromise();
} catch (e){
    val = "SomeValue";
}
secondHandler(val);
```

You're catching the error and handling it - so it gets to the success handler.

Comment: @HarishR so apparently - that is not the case. `p` is undefined in `dummyPromise`. Here look: http://plnkr.co/edit/oAqBKK26tmiFdNg8yMkJ?p=preview

Comment: i am still not getting the point you are trying to put across.. it would be great help if you can explain it thru plunker, sorry for bothering but would really like to understanding promised with exception/try-catch

Comment: @HarishR I noticed you've accepted the other answer - does that mean you understand it or do you still require an explanation?

Comment: i do understand the why it works.. i now did understood your example as well... exception is handled does not necessarily means that it is throws.. unless and untill catcher throws it back... great man.. nice example.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how promises work. In your *error*-function your dealing with the error,if no specified otherwise, it will return a new promise which is resolved. If you want to reject it, you hav to do it by returning `$q.reject();`
Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q). I find the example from `$q.reject();` explains it well.

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
  // success: do something and resolve promiseB
  //          with the old or a new result
  return result;
}, function(reason) {
  // error: handle the error if possible and
  //        resolve promiseB with newPromiseOrValue,
  //        otherwise forward the rejection to promiseB
  if (canHandle(reason)) {
   // handle the error and recover
   return newPromiseOrValue;
  }
  return $q.reject(reason);
});
```